# What is wrong with this VBA Code

Tags: database, vba, ms-access, ms-access-2007, ms-access-2010

Please tell me what is wrong with this code.
It shows error...
"The rowsourcetype property must be set to value list to use this"

```
Private Sub Form_Load()
     Dim db As DAO.Database
     Dim rs As DAO.Recordset
     Dim strSQL As String, strItem As String

    strSQL = "SELECT CustomerID, CompanyName FROM Customers"
    Set db = CurrentDb
    Set rs = db.OpenRecordset(strSQL)
    Do Until rs.EOF
         strItem = rs.Fields("CustomerID").Value & ";" _
         & rs.Fields("CompanyName").Value
    Me.List1.AddItem strItem      ' Row Source Type must be Value List
    rs.MoveNext

    Loop
    rs.Close
    Set rs = Nothing
    Set db = Nothing
    End Sub
```

Comment: this question requires also to know, what is in the form and how is the list1 configured...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Go to the properties of the list-item, in data you find the property "Row Source Type" and set this to "Value list".
Or you can do ths in the code by putting

```
Me.Liste3.RowSourceType = "Value List"
```

right at the start of your code after the line     `Dim strSQL As String, strItem As String`

Hope this helps!
Max

Comment: It works but the result showed in opposite order in listbox. i mean to say that first it show company name and then it show companyid. i wrote the code you suggested in form load event. further how should i write columnwidths through code. i wrote 5cm ';' 5cm but it produce error. thanks

Comment: office apps use Points and not mm/cm. You need to convert cm to points. Basically for cm->points: `Xpts = Ncm / 2.54 * 72` (usually it is 72 dpi).

Comment: @RizwanSafdar about the opposite order: easiest way to put a sort by-clause in your SQL-string. If it Comes wrong way, sort it other way round.